# How can I close the panel in VS Code using the escape key?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing a VS Code keybinding to be able to close Panel using escape key. Here is the keybinding:

```json
  {
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
    "when": "panelVisible"
  },
```

However there is one problem. When I open terminal using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, escape wont close terminal unless i move focus to editor. I also tried:

```json
  {
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "workbench.action.closePanel",
    "when": "panelVisible || terminalFocus"
  },
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: Use Ctrl+Esc instead? That's what I do.

Answer (score 1):

You need the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) to make VS Code consume the keybinding instead of sending the key presses for the command you want to bind a keyboard shortcut to to the shell:

```json
"terminal.integrated.commandsToSkipShell": [
    "workbench.action.closePanel"
]
```

Just a bit of forewarning- some shells like using (or are commonly configured to use) the escape key as a meta key, so if you use escape to close the VS Code panel, you might be locking yourself out of some things you could otherwise do (but if you don't notice, it means it doesn't matter to you because you weren't using those features in the first place).